# Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0 while parsing JSON

Tags: java, json

In order to find out weather the JSON element is JSONArray or JSONObject type, I am getting *Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0* error.

My JSON is:

```
{"colors":[{"color":"red","value":"#00"},{"color":"white","value":"#000g"}]}
```

My code is:

```
java.io.FileReader reader = new java.io.FileReader("jsonpath");
org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
System.Out.Println("aaaaaa JSON Class: "+parser.parse(reader).getClass());
if(parser.parse(reader) instanceof org.json.simple.JSONArray)
    System.Out.Println("JSONArray");
else if(parser.parse(reader) instanceof org.json.simple.JSONObject)
    System.Out.Println("JSONObject");
```

When I run above code it shows this output

```
aaaaaa JSON Class: class org.json.simple.JSONObject Unexpected token END OF FILE at popsition 0
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser(Unknown Source)
.
.
.
<rest of the exception>
```

I don't understand why this exception is occurring.
Please help me out.

**Some more details after edit:**

My this code is working fine with the given json file:

```
java.io.FileReader reader = new java.io.FileReader("jsonpath");
org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
org.json.simple.JSONObject object = (JSONObject)parser.parse(reader);
System.Out.Println("JSONObject: "+object);
org.json.simple.JSONArray array = (JSONArray)object.get("colors");
System.Out.Println("JSONArray: "+array);
```

Output of above code:

```
JSONObject: {"colors":[{"color":"red","value":"#00"},{"color":"white","value":"#000g"}]}
JSONArray: [{"color":"red","value":"#00"},{"color":"white","value":"#000g"}]
```

But I want to dynamically parse the JSON without knowing the JSON structure.
I want to do something like this:

```
  if(json is object)
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject)parser.parse(reader);
  else if (json is array)
    JSONArray array = (JSONArray)parser.parse(reader);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you have a non printable character in front of the json

Comment: Without familiarity with the library, I'd guess that another possible reason would be that you're loading an empty file. (Also, your output doesn't include the exception).

Comment: Looks like you have an empty file, whatever you may think it contains.

Comment: @Jens, I don't think there is any non printable character because my another code is runnig fine with the same json file. I edited my post with more details.

Comment: @Vulcan My file is not empty. I edited my post with more details.

Comment: Please check my answerr.

Comment: Look at the difference between your working example and your non-working example: `new JSONParser()` vs `new JSONParser(reader)`. Or, could it be that `parse` can only be called once (as it is in your working example)? You call it repeatedly in the non-working example.

Comment: @Vulcan, Sorry for the inconvenience. Both the place it should be `new JSONParser()` only, I edited my post accordingly. And, Yes you are right I should call `parse` only once. Now I am not getting any error. A BIG Thank you for this suggestion.

Comment: Sorry @jackk , I am not able to see your answer in this post. As I can see there is only one answer provided by "Joe". It would be great if you can post your answer again. Thanks for you response.

Comment: Sorry @kumarhimanshu449    I accidentally deleted my answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're repeatedly parsing the same `Reader`. The first call exhausts it and then each subsequent call sees an empty stream.

Comment: Thanks @Joe. Yes, I should not parse `reader` more than once. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Parse the reader only once. Here is the working code:

```
java.io.FileReader reader = new java.io.FileReader("jsonpath");
org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object p = parser.parse(reader);
if(p instanceof org.json.simple.JSONArray){
    System.Out.Println("JSONArray");
    org.json.simple.JSONArray object = (JSONArray)p;
}
else if(p instanceof org.json.simple.JSONObject){
    System.Out.Println("JSONObject");
    org.json.simple.JSONObject object = (JSONObject)p;
}
```

**Output of above code**

```
JSONObject
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, error may occur when you try to pass wrong path.

**So check your path to json file properly. Try to use absolute path at first.**

Here is my procedure:

```
private static void ReadWithEncoding(String filePath, String encoding) {
    StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
    File f = new File(filePath);
    if (f.exists() && f.isFile()) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f), encoding));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                json.append(line);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

You may run it like this for UTF8:

```
ReadWithEncoding("D:/file.json", "UTF8");
```

For Cyrillic symbols:

```
ReadWithEncoding("D:/file.json", "Cp1251");
```

Answer (score 0):

I too was getting this error ("Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0.").
I was using same instance of com.google.gson.Gson and org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser on multiple threads.
Now I changed the code and created new instance of these on each thread, and that solved the issue.

gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
parser = new JSONParser();